# Obtain custom endnote formatting with reledmac package

Tags: formatting, endnotes, reledmac

I'm using reledmac package and I would ask how to obtain an endnote formatting similiar to the *second example* quoted below, without page numbers, with bigger font size and colon:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}

    \usepackage{reledmac}

    \begin{document}

    \Xendparagraph[A]

%first example (with proper use of endnote)

    \firstlinenum{1}
    \linenumincrement{1}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut \edtext{labore}{\Aendnote{note 1}} et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud \edtext{exercitation}{\Aendnote{note 2}} ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat \startlock (\doendnotes{A})

    \pend
    \endnumbering

    \bigskip

%second example (only to show expected result)


    \firstlinenum{1}
    \linenumincrement{1}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat \startlock (2 labore : note \hspace{20pt} 3 exercitation : note 2)

    \pend
    \endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy it.

Comment: I managed to insert colon using, \Xendlemmaseparator[A]{\hspace*{5pt}$\colon$}, but I still don't know how to remove page number at the beginning of lemmas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, what you should add in your preamble:

```
\Xendparagraph[A]%Endnotes as a single paragraph
\Xendlemmaseparator[A]{~:}%Comma as separator
\Xendnotefontsize[A]{\normalsize}%Normalsize for endnote
\renewcommand{\printnpnum}[1]{}%No page number
\Xendafternote{20pt}%Space between notes
```

Note the two following points:

- There is actually no possibility to disable the printing of page number by type of note. That is why I do `\renewcommand{\printnpnum}[1]{}`
- Actually, you will get a spurious space after the opening parenthesis. I have just send on CTAN a v 2.16.5 of reledmac which fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works correctly as intended. I will wait for a new version which allows to suppress the spurious space.

Comment: I have installed the new package from CTAN but the spurious space remains. How can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are your sure ? please look on the version number.

Comment: I have dowloaded on CTAN. it is version 2.16.4, wait for tomorrow

Comment: The catalog of CTAN tel you v 2.16.5, but the mirror are still on v 2.16.4. In general, it take 24 hour to be sync. And 24 h to be available on tlmgr. I recommand you to use tlmgr to up your version, and to not do manual installation